# Lebesgue Measurable but neither Borel nor Jordan Measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I'm stuck with this question:

"Find a bounded Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb {R}^n$  with positive Lebesgue measure that is neither a Borel set, nor Jordan measurable."

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know how to do the two parts separately - get a positive-measure set which isn't Borel, and get a positive-measure set which isn't Jordan measurable?

Comment: Positive-measure set which is not Jordan I know. But I only know a set with 0-mesure that is not Borel

Comment: OK, do you see a way to put those two examples together to get what you want? (HINT: don't do anything complicated, just ... "put them together.")

Comment: "*Positive-measure set which is not Jordan I know. But I only know a set with 0-mesure that is not Borel*" Put a copy of one (scale and translate if necessary) in the interval $[0,1]$ and a copy of the other (scale and translate if necessary) in the interval $[2,3].$ Then use the union of these sets for your example. (If neither set has positive Lebesgue measure, include also in the union the interval $[4,5].)$ Make sure you explain why the union is not Borel and also not Jordan measurable.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to "find" a non-Borel set in a strict sense of "find"; the existence of non-Borel sets relies on the axiom of choice, and that implies that any characterization of a non-Borel set will be non-constructive. So presumably the question allows "find" to include non-constructive characterization.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why if I take the union of the two sets this union will not be Jordan Mensurable?

Comment: @MatheusManzatto See Dave's comment above (you have to think a little harder than just union, but not too much harder).

Comment: @Acccumulation It depends how you define "Borel." It is consistent with ZF that $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, hence in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the opens; however, ZF does prove that there are sets of reals which are not *coded Borel sets*, e.g. the set of reals which represent countable well-orderings.